# fabric.js: why a border radius of 1px when stroke: true, fill: false

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on a bigger web application which is using a canvas for rending shapes. Now I've got a problem with rendering of unfilled rects (`stroke: '#fff', fill: false`): they always have a border radius of 1px. I was able to reproduce it with a small example; when I set `rx: -1, ry: -1` the border radius is gone, but there are dots visible (because the pixel gets painted twice):

http://jsfiddle.net/NmWvY/1/

The black rect is with `rx: 0, ry: 0` and the red is with `rx: -1, ry: -1`.

How can I fix this?

Greetings,
CK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the FabricJS source, this is how `fabric.Rect` objects are drawn:

```
...
ctx.moveTo(x+rx, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+w-rx, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+ry, x+w, y+ry);
ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-ry);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w,y+h,x+w-rx,y+h,x+w-rx,y+h);
ctx.lineTo(x+rx,y+h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y+h,x,y+h-ry,x,y+h-ry);
ctx.lineTo(x,y+ry);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x+rx,y,x+rx,y);
ctx.closePath();
...
this._renderStroke(ctx);
```

That is, the absence or presence of `rx` and `ry` does not deter the path from being made, and hence stroked. Even if `rx` and `ry` were null, they are defaulted to `0`.

The `strokeWidth` property sets the `lineWidth` with which the path is stroked when `stroke` is not `false` or `null`.

You could [try changing `strokeWidth`](http://jsfiddle.net/vpQFA/) to change the width of the stoke. It isn't really quite clear what exactly the problem is with strokes always having the width of `1px`, but this should help.

Comment: This, indeed, solves the problem; it seems that there somewhere is an off-by-one error in fabric.js. I think I'll debug that. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this is because of `quadraticCurveTo` and subpixel rendering. Once you scale shape a bit, this doesn't seem to happen. I updated fiddle, making black rect 2x scaled (and updating Fabric from 0.9 to 1.1.16 while at it) — http://jsfiddle.net/NmWvY/7/ We can probably solve this by avoiding `quadraticCurveTo` when rx/ry are `0`. Please file an issue on github, I'll get to it when I have a chance.

Comment: @kangax this is exactly how I solved it in a patched fabric.js version. I [filed a bug](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/691).